# php check one array against another for all matches

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays that list people, and I'm trying to figure out which people are in both arrays.

```
$employees = Array("bob", "john", "jerry", "mike");
$homies = Array("bob", "john", "arnold");
```

I basically need to know which dudes are both employees and homies (in this case, bob and john) so that I have a new array:

```
$employees_and_homies = Array("bob", "john");
```

I looked at like a dozen other questions on here, but I'm lost and nothings working for this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`array_intersect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
$employees_and_homies = array_intersect($employees, $homies);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print_r(array_intersect ($employees, $homies));
```

@Ref : https://www.php.net/array_intersect